ValidateSet on class instance method param; Powershell 5.1
ValidateSet is a great feature in Powershell 5.1. Unfortunately, you cannot use it on parameters in class instance (object) functions.
Is there a way to force the use of ValidateSet anyways?
Note: After playing around for a while, I settled on a way to do it. Hopefully, if anyone is struggling in the future with the same issue, my answer can help. If you have another way of doing this, please add your own answer.

Class Powershell {
   $version
   Powershell($profile) {

   }

   SetVersion($version) {  try { [ValidateSet(5, 5.1, "5", "5.1", 7, 7.4, "7", "7.4")]$_version = $version}
      catch {
            Write-Host "SetVersion IllegalArgumentException version == $version. See method header for list of valid args -ForegroundColor DarkRed
            Write-Host "Exiting Script..." -ForegroundColor DarkRed
            exit
      }

      *rest of function*
      
   }
}

